# React Native listItem condition if / else

Tags: react-native

I list with listItem
if "count" is not 0 I want to show badge

```
list.map((l, i) => (
   <ListItem
   containerStyle={{ width: '100%', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: '#eee'}}
   style={{ paddingLeft: 0 }}
   key={i}
   leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.avatar } }}
   title={l.subject}
   subtitle={l.username}
   badge={{ value: l.count, textStyle: { color: 'white' } , badgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#333', padding:8 } }} }
   chevron
   />
))
```

It was dissolved

```
badge={l.count !== 0 ? { value: l.count, textStyle: { color: 'white' } , badgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#333', padding:8 } } : null}
```

Comment: Perhaps a ternary with an empty value?
`badge={l.count > 0 {value: l.count... etc} : undefined}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
   badge={ l.count>0? { value: l.count, textStyle: { color: 'white' } , badgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#333', padding:8 } }} : null }
```

Comment: badge=badge={l.count != 0 { value: l.count, textStyle: { color: 'white' } , badgeStyle: { backgroundColor: '#333', padding:8 } }} JSX ERROR

Comment: Remove one badge=